# Donors cannot update credit card info with iATSPayments?

Tags: iatspayments

Drupal 7.91
CiviCRM 5.51.1
iATSPayments 1.7.4

Our donors do not have the ability to update their credit card on file. They have the "View" link but not the edit.

I checked the settings in /civicrm/admin/contribute/iatssettings and the 3 enable self-service boxes are checked.
I looked at the Drupal permissions. The CiviContribute: edit contributions was not enabled for Donors. I checked that box, flushed cache, but they still do not see the Edit link.

I checked my css to see if I had hidden that link. It also does not show as hidden in Chrome Inspector.

I tried several urls but get access denied messages
[https://secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/contact/edit/iatscustomerlink?reset=1&cid=11482&customerCode={iATS](https://secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/contact/edit/iatscustomerlink?reset=1&cid=11482&customerCode=%7BiATS) Code}&paymentProcessorId=3&is_test=0

This one gives me a hard fail
[https://secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&crid=964&cs={contact.checksum}](https://secure.radiusinternational.org/civicrm/contribute/updatebilling?reset=1&crid=964&cs=%7Bcontact.checksum%7D)

Any ideas what I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first url you list is an iATS-specific, internal admin-only url for managing cards on file, not something that you would ever give to a client or donor.

The second one looks like it might be one that you're generating yourself. I noticed in my testing that the anonymous-access links for updating your credit card in the invoice now no longer have a crid parameter, but instead an oid parameter (corresponding to the contribution id).

An authenticated unprivileged user in their own dashboard will get a url to edit their billing information that looks like your second url without the checksum.

I've tested all these options with the current iATS 1.7.4 and they are working on my Drupal 7 test site.

Full details here: https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues/390

Comment: Posted https://github.com/iATSPayments/com.iatspayments.civicrm/issues/390